# Why does the Bible not speak of the death of Rebecca?

Tags: genesis, death, jacob, isaac, esau

In the bible we can read the death of many important people.

Why is Rebecca’s death not mentioned? What can be the actual reason?

Answer (score 1):

[Jewish tradition](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12610-rebekah) holds that Rebecca's death is not mentioned because it involved a great shame, as it was attended by Esau rather than Jacob.

> The Rabbis agree that Rebekah died at the age of 133 years. Her death
> occurred while Jacob was on his way back to his parents' home... Her
> decease is not mentioned because Jacob not having yet arrived, Esau
> was the only son present to attend to her burial. Moreover, the
> ceremony was performed at night out of shame that her coffin should be
> followed by a son like Esau (Pesiḳ. l.c.; Midr. Agadah on Gen. l.c.).

More specifically, the Pesikta de-Rav Kahana (c. 700 c.e.) says:

> Who will go before her bier? Abraham is dead, Isaac’s eyes are dim
> and he sits in his house, and Jacob has fled from Esau. If the wicked
> Esau were to go before her, people would say: “Cursed be the breasts
> that nursed such a man as this.” What did they do? They brought her
> out at night. Since her bier did not go out in public, the Torah did
> not mention her death, and merely alluded to it in Gen. 35:8:
> “Deborah, Rebekah’s nurse, died” (Pesikta de-Rav Kahana, Zakhor, ed.
> Mandelbaum, 3:1).

The above, of course, is not biblical. However it indicates how respected Jewish commentators thought about the question. There is a large body of ancient Jewish literature detailing Esau's evil character and wicked deeds.

Answer (score 1):

The Book of Jubilees says that Rebekah died at 155 years of age which seems more logical as this would have her dying 5 years before Isaac instead of 17 years.
Some scholars are now saying she outlived Isaac by 2 years which would explain why her death wasnt recorded.
She had not died yet!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Both the books if Jubilee and Jashur indicate Jacob saw Rebecca before she died.  These are honored holy books that did not make it into the biblical canon. The lack of mention concerning her death and the mention of Deborah’s death, her handmaiden, could indicate she died after Deborah.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.